# What does the Migration Log for MSDSS, that FMU uses, look like?

Tags: active-directory, migration, novell, edirectory

I need to migrate some files on a Netware server to an NTFS share.  I want to use the MS FMU (File Migration Utility) tool to do so.

FMU requires a mapping file, to map eDirectory objects to AD objects, that it expects to have come from the MSDSS service (MS Directory Synchronization Services) but I do not wish to neither install, nor run this tool on the production environment since they are already synchronized in another fashion.

I just need a good sample of what the Migration log file should look like, and I can generate it, since the usernames are the same and the contexts in both eDirectory and AD are predictable.

I found a sample on a forum post, but it is unclear if the formatting survived or was lost, through the pre-SO/SF/SU interfacing of that forum.  If you have such a file handy that you could share, or even just comment on how the file I have looks in terms of formatting, that would be great.

```
Session 9: {21AD8B68-2A42-459e-BD29-F082F47E71B2}  

Started: 01-30-2002 17:14  

NDS Tree: NWTRADERS_TREE  

AD Server: noiis.IIS-IS-NOT-INSTALLED.COM  

O=NWTRADERS/OU=CHARLOTTE/OU=BKD/CN=tbenUser  

CN=tben,OU=NetWare2,DC=IIS-IS-NOT-INSTALLED,DC=com  

user  

O=NWTRADERS/OU=CHARLOTTE/OU=BKD/CN=fayedo  

User  

CN=fayedo,OU=NetWare2,DC=IIS-IS-NOT-INSTALLED,DC=com  

user  

O=NWTRADERS/OU=CHARLOTTE/OU=BKD/CN=Lisag  

User  

CN=Lisag,OU=NetWare2,DC=IIS-IS-NOT-INSTALLED,DC=com  

user  

O=NWTRADERS/OU=CHARLOTTE/OU=BKD/CN=curtiss  

User  

CN=curtiss,OU=NetWare2,DC=IIS-IS-NOT-INSTALLED,DC=com  

user
```

Links:

[MS Services for Netware tool download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=a819838d-acb2-4794-87eb-82a6a3af4be8)
[MS SFN Documentation](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/sfn/default.mspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to generate this file and make it look like the one you have.  However what I found is that the FMU does not like it and gives an error about an invalid header when you try to load it up.  I am thinking that the MSDSS tool keeps some sort of session ID in active directory and will not let you manually create the file.  I hope I am wrong!!  Did you get this to work??

Comment: A team mate of mine ended up dealing with this, and generated the map by hand, such that it is, in the end.